# VSCode: [Django] How to navigate to the desired file via urls includes ike PyCharm

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

[image]

How to realize it so that when I click on `urls` inside `includes`, it moves to the desired file like PyCharm

I've already installed vscode extensions Pylance and Django

I've tried to hold to 'ctrl' key, but it doesn't work. It works when I click on a class or a function

Comment: I do not think the feature you are asking for works. The closest thing you can do is press `ctrl+p` or `ctrl+shift+h`, then it will pop up a search window, there you can type in the text for which file you are looking for or copy paste from the code.

Comment: write an extension that implements a `DocumentLinkProvider` for Python files

Comment: the django extension already has a `DocumentLinkProvider` for jump to template, modify the code to also create links for URLs

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing to me but if you want to go to the link on clicking the url you can do so by holding the "ctrl" key on your keyboard and clicking on the url simultaneously.

Comment: I've tried to hold to 'ctrl' key, but it doesn't work. It works when I click on a class or a function